# American wire gauge - why exactly this ratio?

Tags: gauge

Wikipedia on American wire gauge reads:

> Any two successive gauges (e.g. A & B ) have diameters in the ratio (dia. B ÷ 
>   dia. A) of \$\sqrt [39]{92}\$ (approximately 1.12293), while for  gauges two 
>   steps apart (e.g. A, B & C), the ratio of the C to A is about 1.12293² = 1.26098.

My question is: why exactly this ratio? What's the background behind it?

Comment: Since the gage number follows a geometrical progression of successive diameters (1.123) and the ratio of every six gage it is also standard (nearly 2), it is relatively easy to calculate  resistance, mass or cross section deducting from the next. So every three gage the resistance, mass  per length  and cross section doubled or halved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that they arbitrarily picked a very small size (they thought) of an even 0.005" (AWG 36) and a very large size of 0.46" (0000) and decided 40 sizes would be enough for practical purposes. That means 40-1 steps, and the result follows. That's why *exactly* that ratio.

Why *approximately* that ratio was picked probably had to do with the trade-offs between having more sizes of wire available vs. what was optimum. As it is, we often don't use 'odd' wire sizes at least in sizes AWG 4 and smaller-- the even ones are enough for most purposes (I have a roll of AWG 39 wire, so they are made). By picking a finer step they avoided the ugliness of half-sizes.